# Universal closure and t-satisfiablity / validity

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

**Question:**
In class we've saw the following fact:

$\phi$ is valid $\iff \phi^\forall $ is valid.

However on a test, the following prove/disprove question appeared:

$\Gamma$ is t-satisfialbe $\iff \Gamma^\forall $ is t-satisfiable
where $\Gamma$ is a set of formulae.

The answer was that this is false using the example: $\lnot R(x) \wedge R(c)$

(t-satisfiable means that there is a structure and an assignment that satisfy the formula, whereas v-satisfiable is that there exists a structure that satisfies the formula for every assignment in it)

**Thoughts**

I was trying to understand how come these two "facts" live together, because I assumed that the first one can imply the second one. Would love for an explanation (with some examples preferrably).

Comment: How do you define $\phi^\forall$?

Comment: universal closure: adding $\forall$ quantifier to every free variable in the formula.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formula:

> $¬R(x) ∧ R(c)$

is obviously $t$-satisfiable in every structure with two elements; it is enough to consider a domain $D = \{ 1,2 \}$ and interpret the individual *constant* $c$ as $2$ and the *predicate* $R$ as "__ is Even".

Thus, the assignment $v(x)=1$ will satisfy the above formula.

But no *structure* can satisfy $\forall x \ (¬R(x) ∧ R(c))$ because at least the assignment $v'$ such that $v'(x)=c^D$, where $c^D$ is the element of $D$ "interpreting" $c$ will "falsify" the formula.